# Upgrade Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 17

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I was trying to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS to Ubuntu 17.04

I tried with commands

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade

sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Error is shown something like this

```
W:Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple 
times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2, 
W:Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple 
times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2, 
W:Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple 
times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2, 
W:Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured 
multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and 
/etc/apt/sources.list:2, W:Target DEP-11 
(main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in 
/etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2, W:Target 
DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple 
times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2, 
W:Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple 
times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7, 
W:Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple 
times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7, 
W:Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple 
times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7, 
W:Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured 
multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and 
/etc/apt/sources.list:7, W:Target DEP-11
```

Comment: Don't upgrade until you fix those problems. Upgrading rarely solves problems, and sometimes makes the problems worse. Reminder: You made that problem yourself - Ubuntu didn't break.

Comment: sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
edited the corrupted files in this list. Issue resolved